# servlet filter mapping overlap

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have two filters. And the `url-pattern` are respectively:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ListFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.ListFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ListFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/list.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>AllFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.servlet.AllFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AllFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then how will the two filters work if user access list.jsp?

Answer (score 1):

> Then how will the two filters work if user access list.jsp?

The answer of this question is following image:

[image: More than one Filter Mapping]

For details go to this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)

Answer (score 0):

All filters will get applied, in the order they are defined in web.xml.

For servlets, obviously only one can be executed, and this will be the most specific match.

Comment: i just updated my filters. But the problem is when I have two filters like above, the first one is not executed.